# Transformar una cadena String en una Tabla HTML

Tags: php, mysql, string

Estoy creando un sistema donde uno construye productos y va generando tablas y presupuestos, Se debe implementar una funcionalidad para finalizar y es que si el usuario sale del constructor del item pero desea regresar desde otra área de la web por ejemplo el check out y desea regresar al constructor debe tener todo lo que había hecho antes las tablas, precios etc. Lo hice creando una bbdd temporal donde se introduce Los items, para que no se pierda la información el detalle es que los valores que me devuelve la bbdd debo transformarlo en tablas y celdas para que quede exactamente igual como el usuario lo había dejado, Intente con replace, pero no logre hacerlo, esto es posible?

Esto es lo que me crea la información temporal

```html
<?php
class temporalCarts{
    private $CART_ITEMS;
    private $PRICE_CART = 0;
    private $BBDD;
    public function __construct() {
         require_once 'config.php';
        try{
            $this->BBDD = new PDO(PDO_HOSTNAME, PDO_USER, PDO_PASS);
            $this->BBDD->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $this->BBDD->exec(PDO_CHAR);            
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die("Fail to open Stream with the database server" . $ex->getLine() . PHP_EOL . $ex->getCode() . " " . PHP_EOL. $ex->getMessage());
        }      
    }
    public function setCartItem($CART_PRODUCTS){
        $this->CART_ITEMS = $CART_PRODUCTS;
    }
    public function getCartItem(){
        return $this->CART_ITEMS;
    }
    public function setCartPrice($PRICE_TMP){
        $this->PRICE_CART = $PRICE_TMP;
    }
    public function getCartPrice(){
        return $this->PRICE_CART;
    }
    public function addTmpCart($CART_, $PRICE){
        try{
            $statement = "INSERT INTO tmp_products (tmp_product, tmp_price) VALUES (:tmp_product, :tmp_price)";
            $INSERT_TMP = $this->BBDD->prepare($statement);
            $INSERT_TMP->bindValue(":tmp_product", htmlentities(addslashes($CART_)));
            $INSERT_TMP->bindValue(":tmp_price", htmlentities(addslashes($PRICE)));
            $INSERT_TMP->execute();
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die("Fail to insert products in the server" . $ex->getLine() . PHP_EOL . $ex->getCode() . " " . PHP_EOL. $ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
    public function getTmpCart($CART_ITEM, $CART_PRICE){
        try{
            $statement = "SELECT * FROM tmp_products WHERE tmp_product = :product AND tmp_price = :price LIMIT 1";
            $TMP_CART_GET = $this->BBDD->prepare($statement);
            $TMP_CART_GET->bindValue(":product", htmlentities(addslashes($CART_ITEM)));
            $TMP_CART_GET->bindValue(":price", htmlentities(addslashes($CART_PRICE)));
            $TMP_CART_GET->execute();
            if($TMP_CART_GET->rowCount()!=0){
                return $TMP_CART_GET->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            }else{
                return NULL;
            }
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            die("Fail to read data from this cart" . $ex->getLine() . PHP_EOL . $ex->getCode() . " " . PHP_EOL. $ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
    
}
```

Invoco la clase y le paso los parametros.

```html
 <?php
        if(isset($_GET["item"]) && (!empty($_GET["item"])) && ($_GET["item"]!="")
        && isset($_GET["PRICE_"]) && (!empty($_GET["PRICE_"])) && ($_GET["PRICE_"]!="")){
        $TMP_STRING1 = base64_decode($_GET["item"]);
        $TMP_PRICE = base64_decode($_GET["PRICE_"]);
        $TMP_REPLACE = str_replace("Remove","",$TMP_STRING1);
        $TMP_REPLACE2 = str_replace("-",",",$TMP_REPLACE);        
        require_once 'admin/tmp_cart.php';
        $cart_tmp = new temporalCarts();
        // setters
        $cart_tmp->setCartItem($TMP_REPLACE2);
        $cart_tmp->setCartPrice($TMP_PRICE);
        $cart_tmp->addTmpCart($cart_tmp->getCartItem(), $cart_tmp->getCartPrice());
        // READ PARAM
        $cart_read = $cart_tmp->getTmpCart($cart_tmp->getCartItem(), $cart_tmp->getCartPrice());
        if($cart_read!=NULL){
            foreach($cart_read as $key):               
    ?>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" target="_self" href="index.php?tmp_item=<?php echo base64_encode($key->tmp_product) ?>&tmp_price=<?php echo base64_encode($key->tmp_price) ?>">Add more Products</a>
    <?php 
    endforeach;
        }        
      }
```

Y ahora debo rescatar el String que me devuelve la info que tenia guardada el usuario

El String devuelve por ejemplo:

```html
1 ORANGE , A 23 GREEN , A 22 COBALT BLUE , ASDSADSAD
```

Todo ese string debo transformarlo en una tabla y en cada celda un texto, asi lo iba haciendo, pero no me resulta

```html
    <tbody id="first_tabs">
                                 <?php if(isset($_GET["tmp_item"]) 
                                         && (!empty($_GET["tmp_item"])) 
                                         && ($_GET["tmp_item"]!="")
                                         && isset($_GET["tmp_price"])
                                         && (!empty($_GET["tmp_price"]))
                                         && ($_GET["tmp_price"]!="")){
                                        include_once 'admin/tmp_cart.php';
                                        $tmp_items = new temporalCarts();
                                        $tmp_items->setCartItem(base64_decode($_GET["tmp_item"]));
                                        $tmp_items->setCartPrice(base64_decode($_GET["tmp_price"]));
                                        $tmp_name = $tmp_items->getCartItem();
                                        $STR_REPLACE_1 = str_replace(",","<tr><td></td></tr>",$tmp_items->getCartItem());
                                        echo $tmp_items->getCartItem();
                                         }
                                                                    
                                     ?>
                                   
                                         <?php  ?>
                                 </tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que se me ocurre que podrias hacer es descomponer la cadena con [explode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) y despues lo que resulte ponerlo en la tabla, de la siguiente manera:

```
$STR_EXPLODE_1 = explode(",", $tmp_items->getCartItem());
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $STR_EXPLODE_1[0]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $STR_EXPLODE_1[1]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $STR_EXPLODE_1[2]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $STR_EXPLODE_1[3]; ?></td>
</tr>
```

Edición:

Para cuando no sepas los indices puedes hacer un ciclo foreach, de la siguiente manera:

```
foreach($STR_EXPLODE_1 as $EXPLODE_1) {
    $EXPLODE_1 = trim($EXPLODE_1);
    <td><?php echo $EXPLODE_1; ?></td>
}
```

Espero te pueda servir.

Comment: Y si no conozco los indices de la String? ya que siempre seran valores diferentes

Comment: A ok es que pense que siempre serian los mismos indices deja lo investigo y me dices si funciona...

Comment: @CarlosEstarita, entonces tienes que obtener la cantidad de elementos que contengan el arreglo "en este caso `$STR_EXPLODE_1`" y hacer un foreach por cada elemento de `$STR_EXPLODE_1`.